# Difference between `sync` and `await` in netty

Tags: netty

What is the difference between the `sync` and `await` methods on netty? Both block the current thread?

Thank you

Comment: I have no idea what netty is, but here's the difference with the help of Google: [`await`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelFuture.html#await()) - [`sync`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelFuture.html#sync()).

Comment: @MarounMaroun That's probably what the question is about - those docs are poorly written, and would lead most people to ask why there is both a sync and await method that seems to do the same thing.

Comment: Exactly, I read those docs but can't understand the difference.

Comment: Isn't the difference in "*and rethrows the cause of the failure if this future failed*"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I feel like I disagree, the docs are not poorly written. They exists, but you nee to read the API. However if you feel some doc are missing, Netty loves contributions ;-)

So for your question: The difference is indeed `sync()` will rethrow the failure if this future failed, while `await()` will not (and if you need the exception, you need to ask for it to the future objet using `cause()` method.

See API:

http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelFuture.html#sync()

Comment: The interface of sync() only throws InterruptedException. How is it able to rethrow another exception, e.g. IOException?

Comment: Only InterruptedException yes is allowed, but in other cases, this is the ChannelFuture that will host the exception. See http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/util/concurrent/Future.html#cause()